# To save the form (Code in EXTJS)

Tags: javascript, extjs

What is this  url:'save-form.php' ???? is this the url where entered data is going to save after clicking save button ???? I'm not getting error but data is not saving.
var simple = new Ext.FormPanel({
        labelWidth: 75, 
        url:'save-form.php',
        frame:true,
        title: 'Simple Form',
        bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
        width: 350,
        defaults: {width: 230},
        defaultType: 'textfield',

```
    items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            name: 'first',
            allowBlank:false
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
            name: 'last'
        }],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Save'
    },{
        text: 'Cancel'
    }]
});

simple.render(document.body);
```

});

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to listen to click event of Save button
2. in that listener function, you have to call .getForm().submit()